# Visual Studio: two little projects with identical "Command Lines" but one cannot find the headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have a solution with two one-source-file projects in it.  Each file is:

```
#include <mosquitto.h>
```

The first compiles fine.  The second says it cannot find a header.  The source code in the second is identical to the first, so it is a mystery why it cannot compile.

Pre-compiled headers are not being used in either, so it is curious that the /Fp option is issued, I don't see how it can be playing a role.

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files\mosquitto2.0.14\devel" /Zi /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Good.pch" /diagnostics:column 
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files\mosquitto2.0.14\devel" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\Bad.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Another user suggests posting the actual failed output.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Bad, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Bad.cpp
1>T:\MyFirm\dev\MinorProjects\Bad\Bad.cpp(55,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mosquitto.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "Bad.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: As you wish, I have clarified that too.

Comment: Curious, `Good.pch` was added in Release but  built successfully. In addition, Visual Studio creates project in Debug by default.  If one project is set Release  separately  and has its  project properties opened. Then open another  project properties. It will show release version  table even though the project is in  Debug.

Comment: Yes.  Good had the right path in Debug, AND the right path in Release.  Bad had the right path in Release.  I have no idea how I ended up like this because it was a fresh project I only used a few minutes, and I know these settings and wasn't trying to change them.  So it must have been an accidental click??  I also don't remember setting Good in both Debug and Release.  Well, the important thing is that the technical issue is clear, even though I have no idea how I got into that situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned on Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->verbosity=Detailed, and compared the CL.exe commands issued.

To my surprise, the /I include option was NOT present on the failed build command, despite being in the Properties dialog "Command Line" page as pasted above.

The issue was that I was building in **Debug**, but for some reason the Properties dialog was editing **Release** options.  So, while the "Command Line" page was showing the options that *would* be used were I building Release, they weren't used while building Debug.

Comment: This is a well known gotcha when using Visual Studio.

Comment: Indeed, and I should "know better" than to have this problem.  But I'm positive I never even touched release, so puzzled why that came up on the Properties window as a default.  I was just writing a tiny hello world for a comms library, it worked, then making a different version of that, and it didn't.  This isn't something I ever would have gone to "release" for.  It must have been a typo on my part!

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bug (at least I've never noticed it as such) but it is easy to change what configuration the properties window is editing, and if you do that the change sticks, so that the next time you go to the window the wrong configuration is displayed. I always leave it set at 'All Configurations', only ever changing it on the rare occasions that you need to make a configuration specific change,